# Применение оператора "||"

Tags: c#

Имеется такая запись:

```
int manInfo=8;
...
    switch(cMan[manInfo][0])
    {
        case 1||8||17||24:...break;
            case 14||26||37||42:...break;
            ...//и т.д.
    }
```

Происходит вот такая ошибка:

> Оператор "||" не может применяться к операндам типа Int и Int

Аналогично и со случаем `string` и `string`. Может оператор `||` вовсе нельзя применять к `case`? Тогда как в моём случае будет правильным поступить?

Comment: "что делать га?" - учить программирование ;)

Comment: вот и учу))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6373h346.aspx) в C# применим только к типу bool, поэтому в вашем случае будет удобнее использовать примерно такой extansion method:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
...
if(cMan[manInfo][0].In(1, 8, 17, 24)) { ... }
...
```

Comment: ухты! пожалуй применю именно это способ, спасибо!

Comment: Зачем проверка `null==source`? Почему, по-вашему, нельзя проверить `foo.In(2,3,5,null)`?

Answer (score 7):

```
case 1: case 8: case 17: ... break;
```

Comment: вай спасиба!